# Get count of foreign key items from a group by case statement

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys

Trying to learn about mysql joins and have a basic example to work on. I want to figure out how to join two tables and group the counts of sales by age groups.

```
People table:
id            age
1             11
2             23
3             17
4             14
5             24
6             19
7             21

Other table:
id          
1           
2           
3            
4            
5           

Middle table
id          o_id         p_id
1           3            1
2           1            5
3           5            3
4           4            7
5           2            6
6           5            2
7           3            4
8           1            7
9           3            5
10          2            3

age     Total Other for each age group
10-20         5
20-30         5
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select count(*),
    case
        when age between 11 and 20 then '11-20'
        when age between 21 and 30 then '21-30'
    end as aggage
from Customer inner join Sale
    on Customer.id = Sale.c_id
group by aggage
```

You should just be able to join to the Sale table to count sales. [Here it is working](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fdf15b/1/0).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT case
        when Customer.age between 11 and 20 then '11-20'
        when Customer.age between 21 and 30 then '21-30'
        end as age,
         count(*)
 FROM Sale, Customer
 WHERE Sale.c_id = Customer.id
 GROUP BY case
          when Customer.age between 11 and 20 then '11-20'
          when Customer.age between 21 and 30 then '21-30'
          end
;
```

Above works.
[image]